# Disable YouTube video in AngularJS playing in Bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, video-embedding

I have a YouTube video embedded inside of a Bootstrap modal. The problem is that when the user click away from the modal, it closes and the video continues playing. I'm trying to add something where I can check if the modal is closed then to stop the video. I've tried using the `$scope.$watch('videoModalone'`, but no luck.

```
          <div class="modal fade" id="videoModalone" ng-model="youtubeVideo">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <iframe width="550" height="350" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mwuPTI8AT7M?rel=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those that are interested this is how i got it working:

```
     <div class="modal fade" id="videoModalone">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <iframe width="550" height="350" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mwuPTI8AT7M?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Then in my controllers i look for the modal closing

```
$('#videoModalone').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    var outerDiv = document.getElementById("videoModalone");
    var youtubeIframe = outerDiv.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
    youtubeIframe.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*'); 
});
```

and this did the trick now the key to all this is the url to the video 
?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer

Comment: You have used angular js in question and given solution in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 5 Modal

```
  ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
    document.getElementById('videoModalone').addEventListener('hide.bs.modal', function () {
      const getFrame = this.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
      getFrame.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*'); 
    });
  }
```